# C# CS1503 Select cannot infer type, mixed up by System.Func and Func

Tags: .net-core, ienumerable, func

I am using Select() on a collection to create many transform functions.  C# is complaining the Select call cannot infer the type, apparently it is expecting a System.Func<> but is getting a Func<>...?  I don't see the difference.  The exact error text:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Func<Foo, Foo>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Func<Foo, Foo>>' [language-core]csharp(CS1503)
```

The code, paraphrased a bit, looks like (ExtendBy returns a Foo):

```
BarCollection.Select(b => ((Foo f) => f.ExtendedBy(b)))
```

If I specify the types related to the Select explicitly it works, but that's a hassle:

```
BarCollection.Select<Bar, System.Func<Foo, Foo>>(b => ((Foo f) => f.ExtendedBy(b)))
```

If I specify the types but use Func instead of System.Func, I get the original error as when the type is not specified:

```
BarCollection.Select<Bar, Func<Foo, Foo>>(b => ((Foo f) => f.ExtendedBy(b)))
```

So it seems like some other Func besides System.Func is getting used and confusing things.  Is there a way to fix this so Select can determine the type implicitly?  Both pieces of code are in the same library project, with TargetFramework set to net5.0.

For reference, here are my using statements for the file calling Select():

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Do you have a way to navigate in the IDE to `Func` when hovering over it and clicking or Ctrl+B like in Resharper? It's clear that something somewhere in your usings is bringing in both... if both are coming through, you can always do a `using F = System.Func` or some such to disambiguate.

Comment: The lambda expression ((Foo f) => f.ExtendedBy(b)) is what is ending up with the Func (not System.Func).  If I hover over it it just says lambda expression.

Comment: I agree some other Func is getting mixed in, but I really don't understand what that Func is (if I exclude a "using System" and try to use Func as a keyword, it fails).  Regardless in the original problem Func is not referred to directly when the lambda expression is created.

Comment: It's hard to say. Seems like an assembly or NuGet in your dependency tree has a rogue Func definition. You'd have to find it. Maybe post your `using`s?

Comment: While it doesn't get to root cause I think `using Func=System.Func` should authoritatively remove the ambiguity. Not sure... not in front of a compiler.

Comment: I appended my using statements to the question(figured they'd be hard to read in a comment below).  If I  try to do a using Func=System.Func I run into problems https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1239

Comment: Doing a regex search of my codebase I couldn't find any competing declarations.  Not sure how else to figure out where the other Func is coming from.